# How to pass csharp binding variable to Javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, function, variables, binding

I want to pass c# binding variable to javascript function. Here is my code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbID" runat="server" Text="<%#Text%>" OnClientClick="passAccessory('<%#Bind(variable)%>'); "></asp:LinkButton>
```

But it always generates an error : "htmlfile: Not implemented".

And the code is not intepreted `onclick="passAccessory('&lt;%#Bind(variable)%>');"`

Does anyone knows how to solve it ?

Thanks.

**Edit:** I have changed the code to

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbID" runat="server" Text="<%#Text%>" OnClientClick="passAccessory('<%# Eval("lblTest.ClientID") %>');"></asp:LinkButton>
```

And this is the code it's related to, it uses the `lblTest.ClientID`

`<asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("reference")%>' />`

But i received an error: `HttpException. Databinding ... does not contain a property with the name lblTest`. Is there any wrong with my code.

**Edit:**  These posts gave me a clue.

http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/5364.aspx

[I am trying to learn how to bind an IEnumerable LINQ collection to a repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831568/i-am-trying-to-learn-how-to-bind-an-ienumerable-linq-collection-to-a-repeater)

Now i have want to use

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbTest" runat="server" Text='<%#Text%>' OnClientClick='<%#string.Format("passAccessory(\"{0}\");", Eval("Ref"))%>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't do ASP.NET webforms for along time, but I believe it should be like this:

`OnClientClick="<%# string.Format("passAccessory('{0}');", Container.DataItem("variable")) %>"`

Comment: It generates an error: `CS0103: The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: I've updated my answer, maybe this works. It is about 1.5 years ago since using webforms.

Comment: While your answer is correct, this type of syntax can be applied when it is inside a data bound control such as GridView, Repeater or ListView. Looks like the OP doesn't have his LinkButton inside such a control, or does he? :S

Comment: you could call `Eval("variable")` instead :)

Comment: It still has a problem when i use `Eval()` function

Answer (score 5):

You don't want a two way bind, but rather an Eval.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbID" runat="server" Text="<%#Text%>" OnClientClick='passAccessory(\"<%# Eval("variable") %>\");'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried `<asp:LinkButton ID="lbID" runat="server" Text="<%#Text%>" OnClientClick="passAccessory('<%# Eval("lblTest.ClientID") %>');"></asp:LinkButton>` and i received another error which is "HttpException. Databinding ... donesn't contain a property with the name lblTest"

Comment: That means pretty much exactly what it says :-) Whatever you're databinding to doesn't have a lblTest.ClientID. What exactly is the datasource?

Comment: I use linqtoentities to get the data, and fill in gridview with data.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily by changing the OnClientClick event from Code-Behind.

```
lbID.OnClientClick = "passAccessory(' " + variable + "')";
```

Comment: you would have to do it inside the `DataBound`-event, otherwise you wont have access to `lbID`

Comment: Why wouldn't I have access to the LinkButton? According to my knowledge it does not have to be inside a DataBound event. :) The only other requirement that would prevent me from accessing it would be, not putting the lbID inside a form tag with runat attribute set to "server". However the page would not be compiled in that case.