# How to pass a value into a javascript function within an aspx page onClientClick

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to check the textbox value before postback occurs. I set the `onClientClick` value to my function but I don't know how to pass the data to check, in this case I want to check the txt1 entered text.

```
<asp:textbox id="txt1" runat="server />

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1"
                runat="server"
                Text="Save" 
                onclick="Save"
                OnClientClick="javascript:check(WANT TO PUT TEXTBOX VALUE HERE);"
                />
```

My javascript:

```
function check(txt) {
 var pattern = /^[0-9]{1,11}(,[0-9]{0,2})?$/;
 if (!pattern.test(txt)) {
    return false;
 }
 else {
    return true;
 }
}
```

The issue is that this check function is used along the keypress event of the txt1 so I cant use:

```
function check(){
    var txt=$('#txt1').val();
}
```

The whole JS code:

```
$('#txt1').keypress(function (e) {
    var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    var txt = $(this).val() + key;
    if (check(txt)) {
        // do sth
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        // do sth
    }
});
```

How can I tell the OnclientCLick function to get the txt1 value?

Thank you.

Comment: OnClientClick="javascript:... <-- no need to specify the language. It can only be JS.

Comment: It does not meddles with my problem. No matters if javascript: is present or not

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like that :

```
<asp:textbox id="txt1" runat="server />

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1"
                runat="server"
                Text="Save" 
                onclick="Save"
                OnClientClick="check(document.getElementById('<%=txt1.ClientID%>').value;)"
                />
```

---

**Edit:**
Other methods :

1. You can add it on server side : `LinkButton1.OnClientClick="check(document.getElementById('" + txt1.ClientID + "').value;)"`;
2. If you want to remain in the aspx page, you have to put a name of a javascript function in the OnClientClick and implement the javascript function in a script tag :

   ```
   <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1"
                   runat="server"
                   Text="Save" 
                   OnClientClick="validate();"
                   />
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function validate() {
           alert(document.getElementById('<%=txt1.ClientID%>').value);
           return false;
       }
   </script>
   ```

Comment: IE8 does not parse the semi colon correctly. Just remove it. Furthermore it replaces for this line:
getElementById('&lt;%=txtPenal.ClientID%>'). Note '&lt;' and it throws me a runtime javascript error: object not found.

Comment: OK, I have edited my post with other methods : it seems to be impossible to add directly an asp variable in a linkbutton onclientclink... Even the answer given in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311874/how-to-pass-csharp-binding-variable-to-javascript-function) does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You have several approaches.

First Approach:

```
function sayHello(obj){
   alert(obj.id + " says 'Hello!'");
};

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnApproach1" OnClientClick="sayHello(this)"
 Text="Say Hello" />
```

This will pass the Button control (actually, just an `<input` element) to the function and you can then work on it however you please.

Second Approach:

```
function checkValue(e) {

    //If it has a target, use it. Otherwise, use srcElement (for IE)
    var ctrl = e.target || e.srcElement;

    //Do whatever you need to with the text, no button necessary.

};

function bindEvent(ctrl, event, handler, propagates) {
    if (ctrl.addEventListener) {
        ctrl.addEventListener(event, handler, propagates);
    }
    else {
        ctrl.attachEvent("on" + event, handler);
    }
};

window.onload = function () {

var myCtrl = document.getElementById('<%=txtToValidate.ClientID%>');

bindEvent(myCtrl, "keydown", checkValue, false);

};

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnApproach2" Text="Say Hello" />
```

Here, you are binding the events to the controls behind the scenes (preferable) and removing that logic from your presentation layer (your .aspx).

Both approaches will work, but I'd suggest going with option two for separation of concerns.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't think you can pass `this` for "OnClientClick="sayHello(this)"

Answer (score -2):

You simply have to add single quote to both end of your string passes to check function as shown below.

```
javascript:check('WANT TO PUT TEXTBOX VALUE HERE');
```

Comment: The text to be checked is not the text in capital letters but the value of a checkbox... :-)